# Aggregating rows when selecting distinct rows with "bad" data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The title is a bit vague, but let me tell you what I want to do and show you what's wrong with my data.

I need to sum up cell values (sizes) of all unique rows in a table. However my data is sort-of "bad". I am working with MAPI and message size returned by MAPI can differ non-deterministically for same message content.

I have two similar tables/tasks: Messages and Attachments. It's easier to deal with Attachments, since SHA1 hash always correlates with attachment size. Attachment data looks like this (tab-delimited, Excel-ready):

```
Hash Size
0x0015A93FFFB1726E6647F94F47F4998AC699A455 97
0x0015A93FFFB1726E6647F94F47F4998AC699A455 97
0x0020CE1810B56CC17F6CFD0A0B6121592825F7E5 85
0x0086077DD1E4AF6A38014AB505105B05F8F5311E 62
0x0086077DD1E4AF6A38014AB505105B05F8F5311E 62
0x00A6510EEDB20A27B00B23416CF755715647A351 85
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
0x011C9258A0E16E25662E8F3BEE8A1462C175C117 87777
```

This is the query that I use to get the total size of all duplicate attachments on the table:

```
select
    sum(at.sz) as Size
from
(
    select distinct
        Hash,
        sz = Size * ((sum(1) over (partition by Hash)) - 1)
    from
        Attachment
) as at
```

(I am subtracting 1 from the count of attachments to obtain true duplicate count: total attachments – 1 = # of dups for this attachment)

Now, the real trouble is with messages, since MAPI reports message size with all the hidden crap and message size for identical content + attachments can be different (notice that for some messages with same hash, size differs):

```
Hash Size
0x001B05F4D041EB0E61ADDEA45A1F7AFAD5C088AB 3248
0x001B05F4D041EB0E61ADDEA45A1F7AFAD5C088AB 3248
0x001B05F4D041EB0E61ADDEA45A1F7AFAD5C088AB 3260
0x001B05F4D041EB0E61ADDEA45A1F7AFAD5C088AB 3260
0x001B05F4D041EB0E61ADDEA45A1F7AFAD5C088AB 3264
0x001B05F4D041EB0E61ADDEA45A1F7AFAD5C088AB 3266
0x00510D4B3A9D42C8D8E236950B7FBBD5FB716698 12040
0x00D92C8EB7E718EF418BC9D843D760FD1F4B208B 3657
0x00D92C8EB7E718EF418BC9D843D760FD1F4B208B 3659
0x00D92C8EB7E718EF418BC9D843D760FD1F4B208B 3671
0x011683250CC8D779EC3F33C23209C26E27E25E73 5143
0x016D424B6B4B7DDB4856D1660ECBFEBDD3ECACCA 3531
0x016D424B6B4B7DDB4856D1660ECBFEBDD3ECACCA 3543
0x016D424B6B4B7DDB4856D1660ECBFEBDD3ECACCA 3549
0x016D424B6B4B7DDB4856D1660ECBFEBDD3ECACCA 3559
```

With data like this, query above fails to return anything sensible, since count of distinct pairs is not always = 1.

I am fine with choosing any one of the sizes for the same hash and use it in the summation.

Comment: I am at a loss for words, why down-vote?

Comment: So your problem is that your data is bad, not that your query needs tweaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with HashDups as (
  select Hash,
         (count(*)-1)*max(size) as size
    from Messages
   group by Hash
)
select sum(size) as size from HashDups
```

The same construct will of course work well with Attachments.

I don't fully understand the varying size issue. Perhaps the following would be more accurate. It assumes the reported size for each "duplicate" is real, (how can duplicates have different size?). You can figure out the min and max duplicate size for each Hash value by subtracting out the min and max sizes from the total sum. Then you can compute the min and max total dup size. Your final true value should lie within those two extremes.

```
with HashDups as (
  select Hash,
         sum(size)-max(size) as minDupSize,
         sum(size)-min(size) as maxDupSize
    from MAPI
   group by Hash
)
select sum(minSupSize) as minDupSize,
       sum(maxDupSize) as maxDupSize
  from HashDups
```

Comment: This post gave me another idea, so marking this as an answer. Since I'm hashing message content anyway, I'll use the source stream length as my message size.